# ng-model inside $ionicPopup templateUrl is not working with scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel

This is my controller code. Show a popup and on button click, make some validations:

```
UZCampusWebMapApp.controller('PlanCtrl',function($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup) {

    $scope.confirmCreatePOI = function(data) {
        var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
            templateUrl: 'templates/pois/confirmCreatePOI.html',
            title: 'Confirmar creación de POI',
            scope: $scope,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: '<b>Save</b>',
                    onTap: function() {
                        var invalidEmail = $scope.email.length==0 || $scope.email==null || typeof($scope.email)=='undefined';
                        if ($scope.emailChecked==true && invalidEmail) {
                            $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'Email is mandatory'});
                        }
                        else {
                            data.email = $scope.email;
                            $scope.finalSubmitCreatePOI(data);
                        }
                    }
                },
                { 
                   text: 'Cancel'
                }
            ]
        });
    };
});
```

This is the directive code where the previous controller function `confirmCreatePOI` is called:

```
    UZCampusWebMapApp.directive('formCreatePointOfInterest', function($ionicLoading) {
      return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope: true,
        controller : function($scope) {      
          $scope.submit = function(data) {
            console.log("Submit form createpoint of interest",data);
            if($scope.createPOIform.$valid) {
              $scope.confirmCreatePOI($scope.data);
            } else {
              $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'El formulario es inválido', duration: 1500})
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

And this is my templateUrl code:

```
<div id="confirm-create-poi-popup">
  <p> Text </p>
  <p> Text </p>
  <div class="list">
    <ion-checkbox ng-model="emailChecked">Receive notification</ion-checkbox>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <input type="email" ng-model="email">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, after user have clicked on *'Save'* button ( *onTap* event), I would like to check if email has been entered on input field.

But when I check it with the comprobation:

```
var invalidEmail = $scope.email.length==0 || $scope.email==null || typeof($scope.email)=='undefined';
```

The `$scope.email.length==0` expression returns an error because email is undefined, so `ng-model` property isn't working with the `$scope`, I'm not getting any value on `$scope.email`

Why is that? Is the `$ionicPopup $scope` property not working? Wrongly used?

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this with `this.scope.cd_ticket`:

```
var popup = $ionicPopup.show({
  title: 'Validar Ticket',
  scope: $scope,
  template: '<input type="tel" placeholder="Digite o código do ticket"  ng-model="cd_ticket" >',
  buttons: [{
      text: '<i class="icon ion-close"></i>',
      type: 'popup-close'
    },
    {
      text: '<i class="icon ion-checkmark"></i>',
      type: 'common-btn',
      onTap: function (e) {
        return this.scope.cd_ticket;
      }
    }
  ]
}).then(function (res) {
  if (res) {
    $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Alerta',
      template: 'Ticket: ' + $scope.cd_ticket + "<br>Resposta: " + res
    });
  }
  console.log(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a few more places that you could possibly improve upon :)

Your onTap function should look like this:

```
onTap: function() {

    // CORRECTION 1 - should use this.scope instead of $scope
    var email = this.scope.email;

    // CORRECTION 2 - check for 'undefined; first, then 'null', then 'length'
    //  (if the first OR condition is unsatisfied, the rest won't be checked for, saving time and a possible error)
    var invalidEmail = typeof(email) == 'undefined' || email == null || email.length == 0 ;

    // CORRECTION 3 - Either check for existence of 'emailChecked' or initialise it to 'false' in your templateUrl
    var emailChecked = this.scope.emailChecked;
    if (emailChecked == true && invalidEmail) {
        $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'Email is mandatory' });
    } else {
        data.email = email;
        $scope.finalSubmitCreatePOI(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working, same error: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined```. I've updated my question. The function where the popup is showed is called from a directive, maybe that has something to do with the probelm itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the code here: [Ionic Play - Scope Issue in Ionic Popup](http://play.ionic.io/app/801ef243263c).

I created `email` and `emailChecked` variables on a `vm` object in your controller `$scope`.

```
$scope.vm = {
  email: '',
  emailChecked: false
}
```

It is a good practice to pass variables encapsulated in an object, here `vm`, instead of passing/using them as primitive types. `vm` stands for View Model. [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Just a suggestion, you may show validation errors in a toast component, here is one that I am using [ionicToast](https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-toast) instead of using `ionicLoading`.

Comment: Still not working, same error: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined```. I've updated my question. The function where the popup is showed is called from a directive, maybe that has something to do with the probelm itself.

Comment: I don't see `confirmCreatePOI` method in your directive. It looks like method calls are wired up via a directive. Can you make direct calls in controllers and avoid directive?

Comment: Question update, I had copied wrong code, now you can see ```confirmCreatePOI``` function is called. Maybe I could find a way to avoid the directive, but if not case...problem remains with scope

Comment: How `$scope.submit` in the directive gets called? Please post code where `formCreatePointOfInterest` directive is called?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that problem by moving scope declaration before templateUrl.

```
UZCampusWebMapApp.controller('PlanCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup) {

  $scope.confirmCreatePOI = function (data) {
    var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
      scope: $scope,
      templateUrl: 'templates/pois/confirmCreatePOI.html',
      title: 'Confirmar creación de POI',
      buttons: [{
          text: '<b>Save</b>',
          onTap: function () {
            var invalidEmail = $scope.email.length == 0 || $scope.email == null || typeof ($scope.email) == 'undefined';
            if ($scope.emailChecked == true && invalidEmail) {
              $ionicLoading.show({
                template: 'Email is mandatory'
              });
            } else {
              data.email = $scope.email;
              $scope.finalSubmitCreatePOI(data);
            }
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancel'
        }
      ]
    });
  };
});
```